# Where is -> oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/comgoogleappengine-1004

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

I just downloaded the Google App Engine "hello world" app and the pom.xml file is trying to download something from sonatype and fails:

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Fa
iled to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.5.1: Could not transfer artifa
ct org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.5.1 from/to google-staging (**https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/comgoogleappengine-1004/**): oss.sonatype.org: Unknown host oss.sonatype.org -> [Help 1]
```

When I browse to the comgoogleappengine, it's not there - only "comgooglecodemp4parser-1048/" and "comgooglecodemp4parser-1049/" show up.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case this helps someone in the future...

Looks to be a proxy issue as I got off our work network onto a private one and things worked/downloaded.

Interesting thing though is that the "oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/comgoogleappengine-1004/" still doesn't seem to be there. So I would think that the pom.xml file should be changed none-the-less.